# mvc make a querystring array with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I have a mvc project about e commerce. Now I am using a filter for order to product on razor page. For example when page is first load I want to create my action link first querystrings. Then click link change new values.

for example first load my links,

```
<a href="~/CategoryName?newproduct=610">New Products</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?sex=610">Women</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?sex=611">Men</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?sex=612">Unisex</a>
..........
```

Other links must be change then I clicked a link for example click to New Products,

```
<a href="~/CategoryName?newproduct=610">New Products</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?newproduct=610&sex=610">Women</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?newproduct=610&sex=611">Men</a>
<a href="~/CategoryName?newproduct=610&sex=612">Unisex</a>
...................
```

First load,
[image]

Then click a link,

[image]

change querystring, change other links with new querystring....

[image]

and click different link,

[image]

I am sending a model on razor page. Now How can create a model and controller for querystring array? And What should I use jquery or......? I cant find a sample about this problem. Thanks for replies.

Comment: How are you generating those links in the first place? Can you post your MVC view code?

Comment: Whilst I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, you can use `$("form").serialize()` to generate a compatible query string for your model (as long as you have hidden or editor fields for each item in your form that you want to pass).

Comment: I added sample photos above.....